# Do olives affect Torah study?

Tags: food, torah-study

I am puzzled by this line in the Gemara, based on a baraita:

> Olive oil [restores forgotten Torah study]... Rabbi Yoḥanan said: Just as eating an olive causes one to forget seventy years’ worth of Torah study, olive oil restores seventy years’ worth of Torah study. [Horayot 13b]

Where is this coming from?  What is it based on?  What does it mean?  Was any halacha derived from it?

(I love olives!)

Comment: Considering that the standard custom appears to be that people eat olives, I once asked a prominent Rosh Yeshiva and Rav in Israel whether this perhaps is only a problem with raw olives which are not so edible anyway (as opposed to pickled olives which is how they are normally eaten). He agreed that the problem is only with raw olives.

Comment: But why relate it to Torah study at all?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/79988 (as well as https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/25583 and distantly related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/77108)

Comment: See: https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/151383/p/9/t/0.238340740352251721234/fs/xPjAoGKkC5Fa2gYvh2SpJbbyFKYKOW1DsTAvZSMNefKa/start/80/end/110/c and https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/168251/p/124/t/0.084721700996409631234/fs/2r2sEVqWbchmRJf4Yge64XHqLB8E5oxXmr8aUr2mzmom/start/730/end/745/c